# Let n ∈ $\mathbb{N}$, $a_i,b_i$ ∈ $\mathbb{C}$, and let A be the n × n matrix with $a_ib_j$ as its (i; j)-entry. Find det(A).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Would anyone be willing to walk me through this question? I'm slightly confused about the importance of stating that the elements/co-ordinates are the complex numbers within the square matrix - in order to determine the determinant.

Comment: If $n\ge 2$ the determinant is $0$. If $n=1$ the determinant is $a_1b_1$.

Comment: Would you please comment further, Andre? I'm trying to understand the significance of being complex numbers.

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of numbers they are; don't let this confuse you. See Examples 6.6 and 6.26 in http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/primes2015/sols.pdf for two solutions distinct from Jason ' s (though Jason 's is arguably the most natural).

Comment: A complete answer has been given by Jason for $n\gt 1$. If you write down the first two rows you will see they are linearly dependent. Any matrix with linearly dependent rows is singular, has determinant $0$. Complex, real, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thanks Andre and Darij.

Comment: The link I gave above needs to be replaced by https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/primes2015/sols.pdf (and "Examples 6.6 and 6.26" should be replaced by "Examples 6.6 and 6.27").

Answer (score 3):

Note that $a_i$ is a common factor of the $i^{\text{th}}$ row, so $\det(A)=a_i\det(A^i)$ where $A^i$ is the matrix obtained from $A$ by replacing the $i^\text{th}$ row $(a_ib_1\ a_ib_2\ \cdots\ a_ib_n)$ with $(b_1\ b_2\ \cdots\ b_n)$. What happens if we carry out this procedure on a second row?

Comment: Wouldn't the $a_i$'s take the form of ($a_2$$b_1$ $a_2$$b_2$... $a_2$$b_n$?

Implying that we're working on row 2, the $i$ corresponds to the row co-ordinates.

Comment: Unless by second row you mean one step below, so $a_{i+1}$.. and so forth.

Comment: By a second row I mean any other row. The idea is that, if we do this procedure first to the $i^\text{th}$ row and then to the $k^\text{th}$, we'll end up with $\det(A)=a_ia_k\det(\tilde A)$ where both the $i^\text{th}$ and $k^\text{th}$ rows of $\tilde A$ are $(b_1\ b_2\ \cdots\ b_n)$.

Comment: I understand now, thanks Jason.